# Why recv() function in sockets does not return anything?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, sockets

I am beginner to socket programming and I am using C++ in eclipse. The program executes successfully but `recv()` function in server-side does not return anything. It keeps waiting without terminating the program.

recv() function of server program:

```
void Server2::readSocket(){

    if(recv(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Read failed with error " << err << endl;
        perror("Reading failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "MESSAGE: " << buffer << endl;
}
```

client program:

```
void Client2::clientSocket(){

    #ifdef WIN32
    // Initialize Winsock
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed: " << iResult << std::endl;

    }
    #endif

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Client Socket failed with error " << err << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

void Client2::clientBCopy(){

    server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

}

void Client2::clientConnect(){

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Client Connect failed with error " << err << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "Please enter message: ";
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);

}

void Client2::clientWrite(){

    if(write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Client Write failed with error " << err << endl;
        perror("Write Failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bzero(buffer, 256);
}

void Client2::clientRead(){

    if(recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0) < 0){
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Client Read failed with error " << err << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue? 
Please ask me to provide the rest of the code if this is not enough and thank you for helping me!

Comment: `recv` is blocking until data arrive at the given socket. From the context of your question it is not clear that a) data are even send by the client so that they can be received by the server and b) that this is the correct socket which is responsible for the connection to the client.  So either a) or b) is likely the problem but it is unknown which of these (or both) due to a lack of context in you question. I recommend that you  [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order provide all information needed by others to help you.

Comment: There are a lot of possible reasons. Please add to the question what kind of socket this is (TCP, UDP, total surprise for those of us out here?), how it is configured (probably need a [mcve] to get all of the nuances), and how you are sending messages to this socket.

Comment: may I post the client program too? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: oh! this is a tcp socket

Comment: Side note: Remember TCP is a stream and a call to recv can give you seemingly random amounts of data. Do not assume that what you got is nicely null terminated and safely printable with `<<`.

Comment: @ManujayaPremathilaka: what you've posted so far are just more snippets from your code. Only this makes it neither __mlnimal__ (too much unneeded code) nor __reproducable__ (too much essential code is missing). It is impossible to see where your problem is based on the information so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my error.

```
    cout << "Please enter message: ";
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
```

This code line I used in `clientConnect()` method of client program cause the problem. Once I removed that part `recv` function executed successfully printing the the message sent from the client.
I just found this code online and I have no idea what's happening from the above piece of code

Comment: `bzero(buffer, 256);` Fill 256 bytes of `buffer` with 0s.`fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);` read up to 254 (255 - 1 for the null terminator) bytes from `stdin` (the console) into `buffer` and then null terminate `buffr` to turn it into a string. This means that the `bzero` line is pretty much worthless. It also wastes a byte by only reading 254 bytes. Be careful when getting code examples online. Far to many of them are substandard. What you want here is `cin.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));`. What you really want is `std::getline` and `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding,

The recv() function shall return the length of the message written to the buffer pointed to by the buffer argument.

```
int fd_set_blocking(int fd, int blocking) {
/* Save the current flags */
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
if (flags == -1)
    return 0;

if (blocking)`enter code here`
    flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
else
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) != -1;
```

}

If no messages are available at the socket and O_NONBLOCK is not set on the socket's file descriptor, recv() shall block until a message arrives. might be buffer is not copied properly into the file descriptor.

Thanks & Regards,
Gunasekaran J

Comment: how can I set O_NONBLOCK to the socket's file descriptor?

Comment: @ManujayaPremathilaka You probably don't want to do that. Most of the time a non-blocking socket is used to poll a socket for data. It will not help one bit if the socket is misconfigured and can't receive data or just isn't receiving data. This is a complication you don't want until you can figure out why `recv` isn't receiving and probably not afterward.